# \int font problem in ctexbeamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

I don't know why the font of \int is different from others.
Can anybody do me a favor? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{ctexbeamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.7,0.13,0.13}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=mycolor} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=mycolor} 
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\sffamily}
```

in this part:

```
 \item 条件期望函数CEF
\\ $[Y|X=x] = \int{tf_{y}(t|X=x)}dt$
```

Comment: Welcome. I see no `\int` in the code. Please add a minimal frame code that shows the issue. However, I already see a problem, namely `fdsymbol` that changes ***all*** math symbols to a style that doesn't blend with the standard ones. The comment next to it translates to “Provides some additional symbols that can be used to enhance the mathematical typesetting capabilities of LaTeX” which is quite incorrect a description.

Comment: I try to delete \usepackage{fdsymbol}. It works. Thank you a lot

Comment: You should only load packages which are actually necessary in your document. Several of the packages in your preamble are unnecessary in a beamer document. This way, you could also avoid problems like with your `\int` symbol.

Comment: Thank you! I get it.   This is my first time here.  You are all enthusiastic!

Comment: Off-topic: The integrand does *not* have to be encased in curly braces. You may want to replace `$[Y|X=x] = \int{tf_{y}(t|X=x)}dt$` with `$[Y\mid X=x] = \int tf_{y}(t\mid X=x)\,dt$`.